# Will a single piece of a dual channel RAM work fine with a non-dual channel RAM?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I used to have 2x2GB dual channel RAM however the other piece is now broken. Now I'm thinking of buying a normal single-piece 2GB RAM. Will it work just fine with my old single-piece 2GB dual channel RAM?

Comment: You will have to disable dual-channel memory mode for it to work.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/350906/if-the-brand-size-mhz-speed-and-latency-settings-of-two-sets-of-ram-are-the-sa?rq=1